# remove line in csv file if string found (from another text file) in bash

Tags: bash

Due to a power failure issue, I am having to clean up jobs which are run based on text files. So the problem is, I have a text file with strings like so (they are uuids):

out_file.txt (~300k entries)

```
<some_uuidX>
<some_uuidY>
<some_uuidZ>
...
```

and a csv like so:

in_file.csv (~500k entries)

```
/path/to/some/location1/,<some_uuidK>.json.<some_string1>
/path/to/some/location2/,<some_uuidJ>.json.<some_string2>
/path/to/some/location3/,<some_uuidX>.json.<some_string3>
/path/to/some/location4/,<some_uuidY>.json.<some_string4>
/path/to/some/location5/,<some_uuidN>.json.<some_string5>
/path/to/some/location6/,<some_uuidZ>.json.<some_string6>
...
```

I would like to remove lines from out_file for entries which match in_file.
The end result:

```
/path/to/some/location1/,<some_uuidK>.json.<some_string1>
/path/to/some/location2/,<some_uuidJ>.json.<some_string2>
/path/to/some/location5/,<some_uuidN>.json.<some_string5>
...
```

Since the file sizes are fairly large, I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do it in bash.

any tips would be geat.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Does it need to be faster than `grep -vFwf out_file.txt in_file.csv`? Perhaps `awk -F"[,.]" 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($2 in a)' out_file.txt in_file.csv`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot OMG! how elegant. Please put this as an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @jared_mamrot just to clarify, I just did as per your suggestion `grep -vFwf out_file.txt in_file.csv >out.csv` and the numbers add up correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential `grep` solution:

```
grep -vFwf out_file.txt in_file.csv
```

And a potential `awk` solution (likely faster):

```
awk -F"[,.]" 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($2 in a)' out_file.txt in_file.csv
```

NB there are caveats to each of these approaches. Although they both appear to be suitable for your intended purpose (as indicated by your comment "the numbers add up correctly"), posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in future questions is the best way to help us help you.